# Can't commit or push Android project to github, Commit button stolen :(

Tags: java, git, android-studio, kotlin, github

**There is no option to commit i don't know what to do. I searched all over the youtube and google but no solution. I'm trying to commit my first android Project to github.**

There should a commit button right. Or maybe i have to press some sort of key combinations??

*i know this might not be the right place to ask this question but i really run out of options*

[image]

Comment: Did you try expanding the panel?

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: @Prashant yes i tired expanding all possible ways.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Android version 3.6.2 Latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try other available options.
Open terminal from bottom of Android Studio and write as below...

---

1. If you want to initialize repository
    `git init`
2. Link your repository to your project
    `git remote add origin <Your github repository link>`
3. Know status of your github repository
    `git status`
4. Add your all files to git
    `git add -A`
5. Commit this files to git 
    `git commit -m "[commit message]"`
6. Push your code into repository
    `git push <your-branch-name>`

Comment: This is a good workaround, but still doesn't explain why Android Studio appears to be broken for the OP.

Comment: So it's broken for sure. This mean should i reinstall ? What do you advice

Comment: You can navigate to VCS > Commit from top menubar

Comment: Sorry for the late comment kind sir. My issue is resolved after i uninstall everything, turn out "Material Theme UI Plugin" https://www.material-theme.com/  was the real culprit behind it.

Comment: Okey thank You for your response please upvote the  answer also so it's benefit to user more